# Cannot Remove Model in Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm building a SaaS Calendar with Backbone. All source code is here:

https://github.com/zxwinmain/Calendar/

but there is a problem: I cannot remove a model in a collection.

let's see this file:

https://github.com/zxwinmain/Calendar/blob/master/statics-src/js/channel.js

In line 60:

```
var user_updated = function (_response) {
        app.instances.collections.users.remove(app.instances.collections.users.where({
            id: _response.ID
        }));
        app.instances.collections.users.add(user_package(_response));
    };
```

I try to update a model by remove it first then add a new one.

And in the other file:

/statics-src/js/view/component_window_settingsView.js

There is the binding:

```
app.instances.collections.users.bind('add', this.userListAdd);
app.instances.collections.users.bind('remove', this.userListRemove);

userListAdd: function (_model) {
        $('#userList').append('<dd id="' + _model.get('id') + '"><div class="left"></div><div class="right"><a class="administrator icon-flash"></a><a class="resetPassword icon-ccw"></a><a class="delete icon-cancel"></a></div></dd>');
        $('#' + _model.get('id')).find('div.left').html('<span class="name">' + _model.get('name') + '</span><span class="email">' + _model.get('email') + '</span>');
        if (_model.get('is_administrator') == '1') $('#' + _model.get('id')).find('span.name').css('color', 'red');
    }

    userListRemove: function (_model) {
        $('#' + _model.get('id')).remove();
    }
```

The problem is:

When I update the data, backbone doesn't remove the model.

Why?

---

the **_response** is like:

```
{
BODY_AVATAR: "",
BODY_EMAIL: "812531235@qq.com",
BODY_INTRO: "",
BODY_NAME: "测试帐号",
BODY_PASSWORD: "48f31a95b28d5c8f4dfcbecc03670292",
ID: "ac0211e8ad38a7e1ebe788b888601b23",
ID_ACCOUNT: "64bd06e00e5b2680583a5cba9d6762fd",
IS_ADMINISTRATOR: "1",
TIME_CREATED: "1424452480",
TIME_DELETED: "0",
TIME_UPDATED: "1424453119"
}
```

app.instances.collections.users.toJSON() result:

```
{
avatar: "/statics/img/avatar_default.jpg",
email: "812531235@qq.com",
id: "ac0211e8ad38a7e1ebe788b888601b23",
intro: "",
is_administrator: "0",
name: "测试帐号",
time_created: "1424452480",
time_deleted: "0",
time_updated: "1424452840"
}
```

data package:

```
var user_package = function (_response) {
    var avatar = '/statics/img/avatar_default.jpg';
    if (_response.BODY_AVATAR) avatar = _response.BODY_AVATAR;
    return {
        id: _response.ID,
        email: _response.BODY_EMAIL,
        name: _response.BODY_NAME,
        avatar: avatar,
        intro: _response.BODY_INTRO,
        is_administrator: _response.IS_ADMINISTRATOR,
        time_created: _response.TIME_CREATED,
        time_updated: _response.TIME_UPDATED,
        time_deleted: _response.TIME_DELETED
    };
};
```

---

when i run this code in console:

```
app.instances.collections.users.remove(app.instances.collections.users.where({ 'id': 'ac0211e8ad38a7e1ebe788b888601b23' }));
```

the result is [undefined]

Comment: How are you updating your collection? If you're calling `fetch()`, you probably want to pass in `{reset: true}` to cause the collection to reset instead of simply augment.

Comment: @StephenThomas Thanks, When one user has changed his profile, the server will send a message with the lasted arguments of the user via WebSocket, All online users will receive it. then remove the old model and create a new one. If I do fetch the collection when I receive the websocket message, there will be 1 more connection and takes more time I think.

Comment: Are you sure that `ac0211e8ad38a7e1ebe788b888601b23` is in your `users`? And instead of removing and re-adding, why aren't you editing the model and letting model events deal with the changes?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes it's in the users. I tried to edit the model by .set() and it works. but the collection for the model doesn't fire a 'change' event. app.instances.collections.users.on('change', this.userListChange); not working.

Comment: How do you know it is in `users` when you can't find it in there? `'change'` events should be triggered on the collection (https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4e8o8ok5/ for example). Are you certain that you're listening to the same collection that you're changing things in? Are you perhaps assigning a new collection to `app.instances.collections.users` somewhere after you've bound listeners? I think you're going to have to trim your code down to a small self-contained example.

Comment: @muistooshort WOWOWOWO!!! Thanks!! I found the error. in my initialize function of the collection, there is a this.fetch(). and in my main.js it's another fetch(). I removed the fetch in initialize function then it's all works fine. Thanks a lot.